# Getting the average sentiment from Youtube comments

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-data-api, sentiment-analysis, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to get the average sentiment from comments on two Youtube videos. When I do the sentiment analysis for all of the text from one video the sentiment is 1 which I believe is because the text is so long. Therefore I want to separate the comments, do individual analysis on them and then get the average. Any clues of how to solve my problem?

```
import os 
import keys
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import time 
import json
import re
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

saved_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'saved')

def get_videos(product, pr_index):
    client = build('youtube','v3',developerKey=keys.api_key)
    response = client.search().list(part = 'id', q = product, maxResults=50).execute()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    list_v = []
    try:
        video_ids = response['items']
        for item in video_ids:
            if item['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video':
                list_v.append(item['id']['videoId'])
    except:
        raise Exception(f'No video was collected for product {pr_index}')
    with open(os.path.join(saved_path, f"videos_{pr_index}.json"), 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(list_v, f)

def get_comments(product, pr_index):
    client = build('youtube','v3',developerKey=keys.api_key)
    list_v = []
    with open(os.path.join(saved_path, f"videos_{pr_index}.json"), 'r') as f:
        list_v = json.load(f)
    comments = []#""
    for video in list_v:
        try:
            response = client.commentThreads().list(part = 'snippet', videoId = video, textFormat = 'plainText').execute()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            for comment in response['items']:
                comments = f"{comments} {comment['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']}"
        except:
            print(f"No comments for video {video}")

    with open(os.path.join(saved_path, f"comments_{pr_index}.csv"),"w+", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        f.write(comments)

def clean_comments(product, pr_index):
    comments = []#""
    with open(os.path.join(saved_path, f"comments_{pr_index}.txt"),"r", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        comments = f.read()
    comments = ''.join([i for i in comments if not i.isdigit()])
    comments = re.sub('https?://[A-Za-z0-9./]+','',comments)
    with open(os.path.join(saved_path, f"cleaned_{pr_index}.txt"),"w+", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        f.write(comments)

def generate_sentiment(product, pr_index):
    comments = []#""
    with open(os.path.join(saved_path, f"comments_{pr_index}.txt"),"r", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        comments = f.read()
    analyser = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    sa = analyser.polarity_scores(comments)
    print(f"Sentiment analysis score for product {pr_index} is: {sa}")

def execute(product1, product2):
    get_videos(product1, 1)
    get_videos(product2, 2)
    get_comments(product1, 1)
    get_comments(product2, 2)
    clean_comments(product1, 1)
    clean_comments(product2, 2)
    generate_sentiment(product1, 1)
    generate_sentiment(product2, 2)
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: It's bundling the text into one and analysing the sentiment of it as a whole which results in a compound score, i.e. the aggregate score, of 1. This would indicate that the text is completely positive which I know it is not. So what I want to know if there is a way to separate the comments and analyse them separately and then get the average score from each comment.

Comment: Im not sure this is a question about the API i think this is a question about how to go about formating analytics of text.  Not exactly sure that is a programming question which means you may be posting this question on the wrong site.